# 2 Questions: ArrayList alternative? And how do I stop my Thread from freezing when my mouse exits?

Tags: java

1)
So I have a game where a cannon shoots bullets and it adds the Bullet.class in an arraylist, but every single time I add or delete an object in that arraylist it laggs the game/thread. Is there any ArrayList alternatives besides a Bullet[] array?

SOLVED: It's my graphics card. LOL.

2)
I use the mouse in my game too, but when the mouse leaves the game window the game freezes. I think this is because it's run in the same thread, but I'm still not too sure. How can I get this problem to stop?

Bullet Class:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Bullet {
    public static ArrayList<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<Bullet>();

    private int id;
    private double velX, velY, x, y;
    private double r;
    private boolean isAlive;

    public int getId(){return id;}
    public double getX(){return x;}
    public double getY(){return y;}
    public double getVelX(){return velX;}
    public double getVelY(){return velY;}
    public double getRotation(){return r;}
    public boolean isAlive(){return isAlive;}
    public Rectangle getBounds(){Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int)x-32, (int)y-12, 32, 32); return r;}

    public void setX(double x){this.x = x;}
    public void setY(double y){this.y = y;}
    public void setVelX(double x){this.velX = x;}
    public void setVelY(double y){this.velY = y;}
    public void remove(){this.isAlive = false;}

    public Bullet(int x, int y, double r, double velX, double velY){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.velX = velX;
        this.velY = velY;
        this.r = r;
        this.isAlive = true;
        bullets.add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to brush up on how to use debuggers and profilers.

Comment: For more specific help, post pertinent code, best if you could create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, ***please*** not a link. Please post your code ***here***.

Comment: That would take to much room. Besides its just pastebin.com

Comment: @CodyJohns: Again, you are asking for free advice, and so your job is to make it as easy as possible for folks to help you. Don't make them go to links that may go dead in a month or two. Please understand that this site is not just for answering your question, but for helping folks with similar problems in the future, and dead links only hurt this site. So in the future, no code links, only code please.

Comment: Please don't delete your question that way. Question rolled back. Why did you delete it? Have you identified the problem? If so what was causing it?

Comment: Instead of just creating objects in an ArrayList I'll just make a big Bullet[] array and store objects in that and iterate when the array is full. And no body even bothered to ask question 2 which doesn't need any code as far as I know.

Comment: `" And no body even bothered to ask question 2 which doesn't need any code as far as I know."` -- then you haven't bothered to read my answer. Point 2. If that doesn't answer your question, then yes, you ***do*** need to post pertinent code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question #1 was just my cheap graphics chip. One way to solve that.

Question #2 when the mouse exited the screen the game froze. I added to my main class: this.addMouseMotionListener(i); And that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are alternatives to an ArrayList, such as a LinkedList or some other implementation. But neither of those are slow in any way, especially when you are just adding single objects at a time. What I'm saying is that the source of your lags is probably not the addition of `Bullet` instances to a list.

Do you have any other things that happen at that time? Is your list synchronized? Any other locking? Do your bullets include an image file that might be loaded from your disk everytime you create a `Bullet` instance? (disk I/O is slow, don't load stuff while playing)

Comment: I have a picture of a bullet, but it's not included in the Bullet.class its in another class where the bullets are drawn.

Comment: @CodyJohns: do you read the picture in once, or do you read the image in repeatedly? You should read it in once, say in the class's constructor and save it to either a BufferedImage or ImageIcon variable (depending on how you plan to display it).

Comment: The image is already loaded in a BufferedImage variable in a separate class.

Comment: How many bullets are you adding? If you have an event handler setup for keypress it might be sending a bullet every <key repeat rate> until you let go.

Answer (score 0):

1. `" but every single time I add or delete an object in that arraylist it laggs the game/thread."`: I'll bet that you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on in that your problem likely has nothing to do with ArrayList being slow or causing a lag, and everything to do with something wrong with your code, with there being an unidentified bug that you will need to find.
2. Your game freezes because you're tying up the Swing event thread with some long-running code. To solve this, do the long-running code in a background thread or use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) if all you need is animation. Please have a look at the [Concurrency in Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: I meant if there was any other type of array i can use instead of an arraylist.

Comment: @CodyJohns: first be sure that this is causing your problems.

Comment: @CodyJohns have you even read his answer? The array or list is not the problem here.

Comment: @f1sh: array or list *may* not be the problem. Your suggestions are good by the way. 1+ to your answer.

Comment: It is. Whenever I removed the bullets.remove(bullet1) the lagg from removing the bullet went away.

Comment: @CodyJohns: that proves nothing. It could be that your bullet code is bad. Again, don't assume that the ArrayList is at fault, and I still strongly believe that likely it is not. But until you show code, our debate is little more than an [angels on the head of a pin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_many_angels_can_dance_on_the_head_of_a_pin%3F) debate.

Comment: I linked my bullet class in the original post.